# Why does \widehat behave differently if I insert \hspace{0pt}?

Tags: math-mode, accents

I am getting some inexplicable behaviour from `\widehat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
\fbox{$\widehat{\mathcal{C}}$}, 
\fbox{$\widehat{\hspace{0pt}\mathcal{C}}$}, 
\fbox{$\widehat{\mathcal{C}\hspace{0pt}}$},
\fbox{$\widehat{\hspace{0pt}\mathcal{C}\hspace{0pt}}$}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: output]

Notice that the hat is misaligned in the first instance, but correctly aligned in all the other instances. Why does `\hspace{0pt}` make such a difference?

Also, how can I replicate this effect for other alignment problems? At the moment I am having trouble with the bounding boxes for the script font I am using...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you put an accent over a single character, TeX uses information in the font metrics to shift the accent to take some account of the slope of the italic letters. Which is why the first one shifts. If you put an accent over a more complicated math list then it's just centered over the list.

Comment: which means that in fact, only the first picture is correctly aligned.

Comment: @Jean-ChristopheDubacq well, there is never "correct" in matters of taste, but it does mean that it is intentional. Because the wide hat and the C are quite fat, reasonable people could disagree on how much to shift. If you try  `$\dot{f}\qquad\dot{\hspace{0pt}f}$` then it is clear to see _why_ TeX uses the italic slope as the dot appears to fall off the back of the f if just centered over its bounding box. TeX does not have information about the letter shape, only metric information so it has to make decisions based on that which will inevitably work better for some letter shapes than others.

Comment: @David: I'd go as far as to say this is _incorrect_ (as in "error in the font metrics"). To be precise, the font metrics contain an _explicit_ shift amount for accents over `\mathcal{C}`, namely, the accent is shifted by 13.89% of the design size (from `cmsy10.pl`: `CHARACTER O 103` has `KRN O 60 R 0.138893`). I think this also [looks bad](http://i.stack.imgur.com/17oUr.png) for `\hat{\mathcal{C}}`. Yes, the hat has to be shifted, but not _that much_.

Answer (score 9):

David Carlisle explained why `\hspace{0pt}` makes such a difference. I'd like to explain how one could change the behaviour of accents over `\mathcal{C}` so that they're not that much off to the right. In fact, I'd go as far as to say that there's an error in the font metrics of the `\mathcal` font `cmsy10`. My solution works on UNIX type systems; here's a comparison of the unpatched versus patched font metrics.

[image: unpatched and pathed]

I think that the patched version in the right looks much better. To produce the patched font metrics, run the following shell script in your current TeX directory:

```
for i in 5 6 7 8 9 10
do tftopl $(kpsewhich cmsy$i.tfm) |
     sed '
     /(LABEL O 103)/d
     /(LABEL O 104)/a\ \ \ (LABEL O 103)' > modcmsy$i.pl
   pltotf modcmsy$i.pl
   rm modcmsy$i.pl
done
```

This will produce 6 files `modcmsy5.tfm` to `modcmsy10.tfm`. (If you think that the accents are still too far to the right, replace `104` with `113` in the shell script¹.) Now the LaTeX file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9><10>gen*modcmsy%
      <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>modcmsy10%
      }{}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy5 CMSY5 <cmsy5.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy6 CMSY6 <cmsy6.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy7 CMSY7 <cmsy7.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy8 CMSY8 <cmsy8.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy9 CMSY9 <cmsy9.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy10 CMSY10 <cmsy10.pfb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
$\dot{\mathcal C}$ $\tilde{\mathcal C}$ $\widehat{\mathcal C}$
\end{document}
```

will produce as output the right part in the above image, and the accent correction will work for all font sizes. ([Thanks, egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59916), for telling me about `\pdfmapline`!) Personally, I don't like the `\widehat` from `amsfonts` so much, so I'd just omit `\usepackage{amsfonts}` if possible:

[image: unpatched and pathed]

¹<sub>Just a short explanation: `103` (octal number!) is the position of `\mathcal{C}` in the font. In the original font metrics, accents over `\mathcal{C}` are shifted to the right by the same amount as over `\mathcal{B}`. In the patched version it's the same as over `\mathcal{D}` (`104` in base-8); the alternative `113` corresponds to `\mathcal{K}`.</sub>

Comment: @HendrikVogt The best method would be to build a virtual font `modcmsy10` based on `cmsy10`, in which you map all characters to the same and add the kerning pair. The same would be needed for all other `cmsyX` and `cmsyb files. Then you could build a package file where redeclaring the font shapes you find in `omscmsy.fd` for using the virtual font.