# Why will TeX only find my tfm file for 11pt and 12pt fonts, not for 10pt?

Tags: fonts, font-metrics

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59740) I did something one shouldn't really do: I modified the font metric file `cmsy10.tfm` and saved it in my working TeX directory without changing the name. This had the desired effect: Compilation of my LaTeX file containing `\hat{\mathcal C}` produced a different positioning of the hat due to the modification in the font metrics.

However, this was done with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
```

It also works with `11pt`, but if I try it with `10pt`, I get the original font metrics although the output of `pdflatex` shows that the font `cmsy10.pfb` is used (same as with `11pt` and `12pt`)!

Why does this happen? And how could one fix the problem? (For some preliminary testing the method with unchanged filenames is rather tempting since in principle it's very simple.)

Comment: I *think* the `cmr10.tfm` might be included in the format file, so it isn't really looked for as a file. Try `fmtutil --all`, but you have to make sure your changed `cmr10.tfm` is found then. Note that you're breaking your TeX distribution this way, be sure to unbreak it again later.

Comment: @Stephan: Thanks for telling me about `fmtutils`! I can't really do `fmtutil --all` since I'm a user with restricted rights on a machine that is centrally administrated.

Comment: `fmtutil` is the version for users (putting things in your home directory). Your admin will be using `fmtutil-sys`.

Comment: @Stephan: Ah, OK. I'm still a little afraid that I'll break something in my local `texmf`s. And: how many (large) files will that produce, and how long will that take?

Comment: I don't know. But changing system default fonts is not a good idea anyway. Why not save under a different name and then use that font?

Comment: @Stephan: If the original tfm is in the format, why isn't used in all cases?

Comment: @Stephan: Yeah, I admitted myself that one shouldn't do that, but I just find it simpler for some quick testing (at least for `12pt` ...)

Comment: `cmsy10.tfm` is indeed preloaded. The metric file is however read in again when the main font size is not 10pt because the font is used `scaled 1095` and `scaled 1200` respectively for 11pt and 12pt. Changing the name and modifying the connected `\DeclareFontShape` declaration seems the best road.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmsy10.tfm` is indeed preloaded. The metric file is however read in again when the main font size is not 10pt because the font is used `scaled 1095` and `scaled 1200` respectively for 11pt and 12pt.

If you rename the modified `cmsy10.tfm` say to `modcmsy10.tfm` and do the same changes to `cmsy5`, `cmsy6`, `cmsy7`, `cmsy8`, `cmsy9`, `cmbsy5`, `cmbsy6`, `cmbsy7`, `cmbsy8`, `cmbsy9` and `cmbsy10`, writing

```
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9><10>gen*modcmsy%
      <10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>modcmsy10%
      }{}
\DeclareFontShape{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}{%
      <5><6><7><8><9>gen*modcmbsy%
      <10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>modcmbsy10%
      }{}
```

in the preamble should bring you on track more easily.

You have also to teach `pdftex` that the fonts are really the old ones. So you should add to the preamble

```
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy10 CMSY10 <cmsy10.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy5 CMSY5 <cmsy5.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy6 CMSY6 <cmsy6.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy7 CMSY7 <cmsy7.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy8 CMSY8 <cmsy8.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmsy9 CMSY9 <cmsy9.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy10 CMBSY10 <cmbsy10.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy5 CMBSY5 <cmbsy5.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy6 CMBSY6 <cmbsy6.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy7 CMBSY7 <cmbsy7.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy8 CMBSY8 <cmbsy8.pfb}
\pdfmapline{+modcmbsy9 CMBSY9 <cmbsy9.pfb}
```

You may also save a file `modcmsy.map` with the following contents

```
modcmsy10 CMSY10 <cmsy10.pfb
modcmsy5 CMSY5 <cmsy5.pfb
modcmsy6 CMSY6 <cmsy6.pfb
modcmsy7 CMSY7 <cmsy7.pfb
modcmsy8 CMSY8 <cmsy8.pfb
modcmsy9 CMSY9 <cmsy9.pfb
modcmbsy10 CMBSY10 <cmbsy10.pfb
modcmbsy5 CMBSY5 <cmbsy5.pfb
modcmbsy6 CMBSY6 <cmbsy6.pfb
modcmbsy7 CMBSY7 <cmbsy7.pfb
modcmbsy8 CMBSY8 <cmbsy8.pfb
modcmbsy9 CMBSY9 <cmbsy9.pfb
```

and call `\pdfmapfile{+modcmsy.map}`, which would have the same effect. The file can be in any place where `pdftex` looks for map files. For instance, with TeX Live on a GNU/Linux system it can be

```
~/texmf/fonts/map/modcmsy/modcmsy.map
```

Similarly, you can store the modified `modcmsy10.tfm` file as

```
~/texmf/fonts/tfm/modcmsy/modcmsy10.tfm
```

(and the others in the same directory). The `\DeclareFontShape` instruction can go, together with the `\pdfmapfile` line in a custom `.sty` package, say

```
~/texmf/tex/latex/modcmsy/modcmsy.sty
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for telling me what's happening! I tried your solution (so far only with all the `cmsy` fonts, not `cmbsy`), but when I compiled with `pdflatex`, I got `kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 modcmsy10`, followed by `mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for modcmsy10`. So would I need to create even more files?

Comment: @HendrikVogt Right! You have also to teach `pdftex` that these fonts are actually the same as before. I'll add it.

Comment: Great! This is everything but short, but I'm _very_ happy that it can be done just by adding something to the preamble. I feared that I'd have to create some `map` file and use `updmap`, which I badly wanted to avoid for some temporary testing. I didn't know of `\pdfmapline`!

Comment: Wow, only now I read your edit regarding `\pdfmapfile` - that's even better than `\pdfmapline`. Thanks again!