# How to find out if a math list consists of a single character?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

When accents are placed, the TeX engine gives single characters a special treatment; see the TeXbook, Rule 12 on page 443. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47058) and its accepted answer for details. Thus, for fake accents like those provided by the `accents` package, it would be useful to find out whether a given math list consists of a single character. Examples of single characters: `a`, `\alpha`, `\mathcal{A}`. In contrast, `ab`, `a{}` and `a\hspace{0pt}` are not single characters.

Thus my question: How do I find out if a given math list consist of a single character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Part of the special treatment of single characters in accent placement is the handling of sub- and superscripts. From the TeXbook, p. 443, Rule 12:

> If the nucleus is a single character, replace box `x` *[which contains the nucleus in style `C'`]* by a box containing the nucleus together with the superscript and subscript of the Acc atom, in style `C`, and make the sub/superscripts of the Acc atom empty; ...

Roughly speaking, the effect is that in `\hat{a}^H`, the `H` is "attached" to the `a`, whereas in `\hat{\kern0pt a}^H` it is "attached" to `\hat{\kern0pt a}` and thus placed quite a bit higher. Here's an `\ifsingle` command (with a true- and a false-branch), based on this idea. First the output:

[image: output of test code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\ifsingle[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\mathaccent"0362{#1}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{$\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
\newcommand*\test[1]{$#1$ is\ifsingle{#1}{}{ not} a single character\par}
\newcommand*\stupida{\string a}
\newcommand*\awithbraces{a{}}
\begin{document}
\test{a}
\test{\alpha}
\test{\mathcal{A}}
\test{ab}
\test{a_1}
\test{\hat{a}}
\test{\stupida}
\test{\awithbraces}
\end{document}
```

As egreg points out in the comments, `\ifsingle` does not identify `[`, `\sum`, `,` and `+` as single characters. (And I modified the code so that `=` isn't identified as single, either.) However, I think this is not a big deal: in `\hat{=}`, the `\hat` doesn't see a single character, either, since `{=}` is not a single character. Only in `\hat=`, the `\hat` sees the single character `=`. See [this awesome answer by Frank Mittelbach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83045) for details.

Comment: The test breaks when you use a delimiter, a math operator such as `\sum`, a punctuation symbol or a binary operation: try `\test{[}`, `\test{\sum}`, `\test{,}` and `\test{+}`. It works for `\test{=}`.

Comment: @egreg: That's an interesting observation! I'm not sure what to conclude from it. My guess: from the point of view of the TeX engine, `[` is not a single character. What do you think? (Changing the `\mathcode` of `[` to `"705B` will make it a single character.)

Comment: One should go in depth into Appendix G, I guess. My attempt was to compare the heights of `\hbox{$#1$}` and `\hbox{$\mathop{#1}$}`, which gives similar results (but misses relation symbols, in addition to big operators, punctuation, delimiters and binary operations).

Comment: @egreg: I fear that even Appendix G might not help here; I've read it many times. Note that `\mathord\sum` and so on result as single characters in my test.

Comment: @egreg: That `=` was identified as a single character was a mistake in the code. It appears that only ordinary characters are entitled to be "single characters" as in Rule 12. See my edit.

Comment: @egreg: I just see that my `\ifsingle` command can break down if `\widehat` is redefined by some package. Can you tell if it would be safe to use `\mathaccent"0362` instead of `\widehat`?

Comment: I guess it's good, as what you need is only that an Accent atom is produced; usually the font in family 3 is encoded like cmex10.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks a lot! The part with the Accent atom was clear to me, but I'm never sure about the font stuff.

Comment: @egreg: It appears that you were right and I was wrong - the things you listed in your first comment here [are single characters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83045). Moreover, even though my `\ifsingle` command works well for `\mathord`s, the explanation I give is is plain wrong. I'll try and correct this.