# Can one determine the first character of a given math list?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

I'm still pursuing my quest to [code a better \widebar command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60253). I can do bars over [single characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70494) quite well already, but I have problems when it comes to letter combinations such as `AW`. `\overline{AW}` produces

[image: output of \overline{AW}]

which doesn't look nice in my opinion: the bar extends too far to the left; it doesn't take the skew of the `A` into account.

To correct this, I must be able to find out the first character of the argument of my `\widebar` command. For `AW` this is easy, but I also would like to cover the following arguments:

1. `\mathcal{AW}` or `\mathcal{A}W` (where `\mathcal{A}` is the first character),
2. `\sin x` (where an upright `s` is the first character),
3. `\mathchar"0141` (which is just the character `A` from the standard math font),
4. `\left(a^2+b^2\right)` (where some `(` is the first character).

Maybe #4 is too tricky since a large `(` might turn out to be a box and not a character. Of course, fractions and radicals shouldn't come up in the beginning of the argument; personally, I wouldn't want to overline such quantities.

So my question is: given a math list that starts with a character, can one find out what that first character is?

Comment: you cant deconstruct a math list in classic tex, however you could grab the tokenlist and inspect it by hand, similar to the way bm deconstructs math expressions to build an equivalent bold version

Comment: @David: Thanks, I had already feared that one has to do it the hard way. Maybe one can hack into `bm` to solve the problem?

Comment: bm is a delicate thing, treat it with care if hacking.....

Comment: @David: OK `:-)`

Answer (score 3):

This is more or less `bm` reconstructed a bit.  It produces

```
First letter A in \symsymbols
First letter A in \symsymbols
First letter s in \symoperators
First letter A in 1
First letter (
```

On the examples given in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\firstchar#1{\begingroup%
\let\fcmathgroup\relax
\let\protect\@empty
\let\@typeset@protect\@empty
\let\mathop\@firstofone
\let\use@mathgroup\insert
\def\left##1{\ifx.##1\null\fi##1}%
\fc@expand#1\null\valign
\endgroup}



\def\fc@expand{\afterassignment\fc@exp@nd\count@`\a}
\def\fc@exp@nd{\afterassignment\fc@test\count@`\a}
\def\fc@test{\futurelet\@let@token\fc@test@}

\def\fc@test@{%
\let\fc@next\@empty
%\show\@let@token
\ifx\@let@token\relax
 \let\fc@next\fc@gobble
\else\ifx\@let@token\bgroup
 \let\fc@next\fc@group
\else\ifx\@let@token\use@mathgroup
 \let\fc@next\fc@usemgroup
\else\ifx\@let@token\mathgroup
 \let\fc@next\fc@mgroup
\else\ifx\@let@token\mathchar
 \let\fc@next\fc@mathchar
\else
 \let\fc@next\fc@show
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
\fc@next
}

\def\fc@show#1#2\valign{%
%\def\xshow{#1|||[#2]}\show\xshow
\typeout{First letter #1 %
\ifx\fcmathgroup\relax\else in \expandafter\string\fcmathgroup\fi
}
}

\def\fc@gobble#1{%
%\def\xgobble{#1}\show\xgobble
\fc@expand
}

\def\fc@group#1{%
%  \def\xgroup{#1}\show\xgroup
\fc@expand#1}

\def\fc@usemgroup#1#2#3#4{%
%  \def\xumathgroup{#1//#2//#3/#4}\show\xumathgroup
\def\fcmathgroup{#3}%
\fc@expand#4}

\def\fc@mgroup#1#2{%
%\def\xmathgroup{#1//#2}\show\xmathgroup
\def\fcmathgroup{#2}%
\fc@expand}


\def\fc@mathchar#1{%
  \afterassignment\fc@mathchar@\count@}

\def\fc@mathchar@{%
\@tempcnta\count@
\@tempcntb\count@
\divide\@tempcnta"100
\multiply\@tempcnta"100
\advance\@tempcntb-\@tempcnta
\uccode`\a\@tempcntb
\@tempcntb\@tempcnta
\divide\@tempcntb"1000
\multiply\@tempcntb"1000
\advance\@tempcnta-\@tempcntb
\divide\@tempcnta"100
\edef\fcmathgroup{\the\@tempcnta}%
\uppercase{\fc@expand a}}

\makeatother




\begin{document}

$a$

%\tracingall
$\firstchar{\mathcal{AW}}$

$\firstchar{\mathcal{A}W}$

$\firstchar{\sin x}$

$\firstchar{\mathchar"0141}$

$\firstchar{\left(a^2+b^2\right)}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\fc@mathchar@` part is the best.  I got to the end, having skimmed the big ugly TeX arithmetic part, and thought "but what if the character is given by its code?"  And there it is: `\uppercase{a}` gets a *typesetting* construct into the *input*.  Clever!