# How to customize a newcommand?

Tags: math-mode, macros, vector

I want to customize a command `\myvec{arg}`.

If the argument is a single character, then `\bm{arg}`

else then `\vv{arg}`

Comment: It would have been helpful to have shown which packages `\bm` and `\vv` were coming from by giving a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2693).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

Adapting code from:

- [How to find out if a math list consists of a single character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/70494/2693)

the following seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
% This code by Hendrik Vogt https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70562/2693
\newcommand*\ifsingle[3]{%
  \setbox0\hbox{$\mathaccent"0362{#1}^H$}%
  \setbox2\hbox{$\mathaccent"0362{\kern0pt#1}^H$}%
  \ifdim\ht0=\ht2 #3\else #2\fi
  }
\usepackage{bm}
\def\vv{} % define as needed
\newcommand*\myvec[1]{\ifsingle{#1}{\bm{#1}}{\vv{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\myvec{a}$
$\myvec{aa}$
$\myvec{\alpha}$
$\myvec{\alpha\beta}$
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]