# Multiple math accents in exponents

Tags: math-mode, equations, accents

- How can I prevent an offset in stacked accents (hat is not in the middle of the tilde)
- and how can I typeset the exponent 'a' in the example below not to be so high and near the tilde?

[image]

For your convenience the code I am using below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  $$ \hat{\widetilde{A}}^a $$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @campa thanks for checking, what is a MWE?

Comment: I solved the first problem and edited the question together with a MWE.

Comment: Maybe this could help to solve the first point https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121937/hat-and-widehat-look-terrible-fixing-width-and-better-positioning

Comment: Don't use `\widetilde` for this; `\tilde` is the right option.

Comment: Seems to be a bug: [`latex`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGYoo.png), [`pdflatex`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm5eo.png), [`lualatex`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4F3Q.png).

Comment: @HenriMenke No, it's not a bug.

Comment: @HenriMenke: I get exactly the same output from `latex` and from `pdflatex`.  How did you produce your screen shots?

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, either use `\tilde` instead of `\widetilde` as egreg suggests or put an empty group before the letter:

```
\hat{\widetilde{{}A}}
```

though I would strongly suggest that you use `\widehat` with `\widetilde`.  To illustrate

```
\begin{equation*}
  \hat{\tilde{A}} \qquad
  \hat{\widetilde{{}A}} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}
\end{equation*}
```

produces

[image: Sample hats]

For the second problem, egreg's approach will give you the superscript at the height you desire.  For the cases with `\widetilde` you can again either add an empty group before the superscript, or more generally a `\vphantom`:

```
\begin{equation*}
  \hat{\tilde{A}}^{a} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}{}^{a} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}\vphantom{A}^{a}
\end{equation*}
```

[image: Sample output]

All images produced from the following document.  Note I have also loaded `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \hat{\tilde{A}} \qquad
  \hat{\widetilde{{}A}} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \hat{\tilde{A}}^{a} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}{}^{a} \qquad
  \widehat{\widetilde{{}A}}\vphantom{A}^{a}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some dirty hacks, just to stimulate better response.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
  \[ \hat{\widetilde{A}\,\,}^{\!\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\scriptstyle a$}} \]
  or
   \[ \hat{\tilde{A}\;}^{\hspace{-.15em}\raisebox{-.3ex}{$\scriptstyle a$}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]