# Width and positioning of \bar, \hat and \tilde

Tags: math-mode, accents

I use the Cochineal font for both text and math, using the `cochineal` and `newtxmath` packages. I only found one flaw about this font: the `\bar`, `\tilde` and `\hat` produce very small accents, whereas the `\widebar`, `\widetilde` and `\widehat` produce very big accents (using the `\widebar` command from Hendrik Vogt's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/can-i-get-a-widebar-without-using-the-mathabx-package/60253#60253)).

To have better looking accents, I tried to define stretched versions of them using the `\hstretch` command from the `scalerel` package. I defined

```
\newcommand{\stretchedbar}[1]{\hstretch{1.67}{\bar{\hstretch{0.6}{#1}}}}
```

and similar `\stretchedtilde` and `\stretchedhat` commands.

Here's a small comparaison of the three versions of bars, tildes and hats:
[image]
Now the `\stretched...` commands give a good result for the *size* of the accents. However, these commands do not shift properly the accents on italic characters, they are too much on the left.

I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121937/hat-and-widehat-look-terrible-fixing-width-and-better-positioning/121950#121950), which introduce a `\shifthat` command. This command allows to manually shift the `\hat` on a specific character, so I guess I could adapt this code to manually shift all three accents on every character on which it is not placed properly. However, of course, this process would be very long, and I'm not even sure it would work for `\tilde` and `\bar` since I don't understand everything in the definition of this `\shifthat` command.

Is there any way I could define a stretched version of these accents, while adapting the shifting of the accents on italic characters? Or to redefine the accents' commands in another way to get a similar result?

Comment: Seems like investigating the "accents.sty" code could provide some useful ideas. The complete code is only a couple hundred lines, but I don't understand it well at all...

Comment: Then let me know if the answer you got corresponds to that request, so I'll give to Sandy G the bounty if it is only one answer.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but I think I'd wait to see if someone gets another idea. And thanks a lot for the bounty, by the way!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `accents` package.

[image]

First, define the accent marks from scratch:

```
\newcommand{\newbar}{\scalebox{.9}[.85]{\trimbox{0pt .55ex}{\textminus}}}
\newcommand{\newtilde}{\scalebox{.9}[1]{\trimbox{0pt .6ex}{\textasciitilde}}}
\newcommand{\newhat}{\scalebox{1.5}[.75]{\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\textasciicircum}}}
```

The arguments in `\scalebox` control the width and thickness respectively. For example, if you want the bar to be thicker, increase the `[.85]` in the `\newbar` command. To make the bar less wide, decrease the `{.9}`. The `\trimbox` command comes from the `trimclip` package. It is needed to accommodate whitespace (vertically) around the accent marks. The nonzero argument controls the height of the accent mark above the symbol. To raise the accents, trim less. For example, to raise the bar, decrease the `.55ex`.

Once the accents are defined, they are called using the commands

```
\newcommand{\stretchedbar}[1]{\accentset{\newbar}{#1}}
\newcommand{\stretchedtilde}[1]{\accentset{\newtilde}{#1}}
\newcommand{\stretchedhat}[1]{\accentset{\newhat}{#1}}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal}
\usepackage[varqu,varl,var0]{inconsolata}
\usepackage[scale=.95,type1]{cabin}
\usepackage[cochineal,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=boondoxo]{mathalfa}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\newcommand{\newbar}{\scalebox{.9}[.85]{\trimbox{0pt .55ex}{\textminus}}}
\newcommand{\newtilde}{\scalebox{.9}[1]{\trimbox{0pt .6ex}{\textasciitilde}}}
\newcommand{\newhat}{\scalebox{1.5}[.75]{\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\textasciicircum}}}

\newcommand{\stretchedbar}[1]{\accentset{\newbar}{#1}}
\newcommand{\stretchedtilde}[1]{\accentset{\newtilde}{#1}}
\newcommand{\stretchedhat}[1]{\accentset{\newhat}{#1}}

\begin{document}
$\bar{e},\hat{e},\tilde{e}\quad\bar{y},\hat{y},\tilde{y}\quad\bar{A},\hat{A},\tilde{A}\quad\bar{\Omega},\hat{\Omega},\tilde{\Omega}\quad$

$\stretchedbar{e},\stretchedhat{e},\stretchedtilde{e}\quad\stretchedbar{y},\stretchedhat{y},\stretchedtilde{y}\quad\stretchedbar{A},\stretchedhat{A},\stretchedtilde{A}\quad\stretchedbar{\Omega},\stretchedhat{\Omega},\stretchedtilde{\Omega}\quad$

\end{document}
```

If you will need the symbols in sub/superscripts you will need to use `\mathchoice`. Combine the macros as follows:

```
\newcommand{\stretchedhat}[1]{\mathchoice
{\accentset{\scalebox{1.5}[.75]{\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\textasciicircum}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{1.5}[.75]{\trimbox{0pt 1.1ex}{\textasciicircum}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{1}[.5]{\trimbox{0pt 1.2ex}{\textasciicircum}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.8}[.4]{\trimbox{0pt 1.3ex}{\textasciicircum}}}{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\stretchedtilde}[1]{\mathchoice
{\accentset{\scalebox{.9}[1]{\trimbox{0pt .6ex}{\textasciitilde}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.9}[1]{\trimbox{0pt .6ex}{\textasciitilde}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.7}[.8]{\trimbox{0pt .7ex}{\textasciitilde}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.5}[.6]{\trimbox{0pt .8ex}{\textasciitilde}}}{#1}}
}
\newcommand{\stretchedbar}[1]{\mathchoice
{\accentset{\scalebox{.9}[.85]{\trimbox{0pt .55ex}{\textminus}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.9}[.85]{\trimbox{0pt .55ex}{\textminus}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.7}[.7]{\trimbox{0pt .65ex}{\textminus}}}{#1}}
{\accentset{\scalebox{.5}[.6]{\trimbox{0pt .75ex}{\textminus}}}{#1}}
}
```

You can adjust the spacing and sizing to your liking.

```
$\stretchedhat{e}_{\stretchedhat{e}_{\stretchedhat{e}}}$
$\stretchedbar{e}_{\stretchedbar{e}_{\stretchedbar{e}}}$
$\stretchedtilde{e}_{\stretchedtilde{e}_{\stretchedtilde{e}}}$
```

[image]

Note that you must `\protect` these if you want to use them in `\section`, `\paragraph`, etc. There is a workaround for using `hyperref` with `\texorpdfstring` in the comments.

Comment: I thank you very much for your attention to this question. +1.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have not the question but...actually this is an only answer.

Comment: It seems to be a good solution! It would be good if the accents could adapt to sub/superscript though, but I guess correcting that with ``\mathchoice`` would not be hard?  However, the issue mentioned by @Schrödinger'scat is indeed more problematic.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Of course you're right. Combining these seems to work ok. Is `\section{\texorpdfstring{$\protect\stretchedhat{e}$}{$e$}}` enough of a workaround?

Comment: That's very good! Removed my comments.

Comment: @Vincent, I updated my post with `\mathchoice`. Also we worked out a solution to the `hyperref` issue.

Comment: Such an amazing suggestion

Comment: Wow! It was already really good, and with the last edits, I don't see anything else to improve. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Flawless solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else faces this issue, there is actually a very simple solution. In fact, `newtxmath` has an option `timesmathacc`, which I did not know about when I wrote the question, to use the math accents from Times instead of those from the Roman text font.

The accents obtained when using the `timesmathacc` option, indeed, already look pretty good.

[image]