# inconsistent width of wide hats

Tags: math-mode, widehat

The code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\widehat{\mathcal{C}_0}$
$\widehat{\mathcal{D}_0}$
\end{document}
```

yields the following.
[image]

I never noticed this effect before, but it seems like the hat on the D is much wider, probably because the letter is wider on top?

Is there a way to make the difference less extreme?

Comment: You should set the hat just over the letter: `\widehat{\mathcal{C}}_0` and `\widehat{\mathcal{D}}_0`.

Comment: that would have a different meaning. i want to apply the hat operation to C_0, not to C.

Comment: anyway, I got it to work now with $\widehat{\hspace{0pt}\mathcal{C}_0}$, as discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47058/why-does-widehat-behave-differently-if-i-insert-hspace0pt